# Covariant derivative for symbolic tensors

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic, tensors

I want to define a "prefix" (D_i) covariant derivative operator CD[] for symbolic tensors in form of a function, i.e. for

```
$Assumptions={Element[g,Arrays[{3,3},Reals,Symmetric[{1,2}]]]}
```

also

```
Element[CD[g],Arrays[{3,3,3},Reals,Symmetric[2,3]]]
```

should be made an assumption, an additional slot is created on the left. So far the only way I found to make this possible is defining a function

```
$Assumptions = {Element[v,Vectors[3, Reals]]}

CDdef[a_] := (AppendTo[$Assumptions, 
    Element[CD[a],Arrays[{3}~Join~TensorDimensions[a]],Reals, 
      TensorSymmetry[TensorProduct[v, a]]]];
      $Assumptions =  DeleteDuplicates[$Assumptions]; CD[a])
```

and effectively writing all the assumption by hand into $Assumptions. But this  could generate a huge list in bigger calculations. All my attempts of the kind

```
$Assumptions={Element[CD[a_?SomeSymmetryQ],Arrays["one more slot"]]}
```

to use pattern that are at least valid for all tensors with the same symmetries have failed. Is there any effective way to proceed?

Many thanks, Hendrik

Comment: Syntax! for starters: not `$Assumptions={Element[g,Arrays[{3,3},Reals],Symmetric[{1,2}]]}` but `$Assumptions = Element[g, Arrays[{3, 3}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]]`

Comment: I think this depends on if you are planning to add further assumptions later on. Or do you think starters can only use one assumption at a time? ;-)

Comment: that's not it, rather the closed bracket after `Reals` : the argument `Symmetric` belongs inside `Arrays`.

Comment: sorry, this was just a typo that does not appear in my actual code, i will correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question; the notion of a tensorial (covariant) derivative is something that is missing in Mathematica AFAIK. I can think of two ways to proceed:

### Option 1

One way is to overload the [`TensorRank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorRank.html), [`TensorDimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorDimensions.html), and [`TensorSymmetry`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorSymmetry.html) functions for patterns that have head `CD`:

```
CD /: TensorRank[CD[tensor_]] := TensorRank[tensor] + 1

CD /: TensorDimensions[CD[tensor_]] := Join[{First[#]}, #]& @ TensorDimensions[tensor]

CD /: TensorSymmetry[CD[tensor_]] := TensorSymmetry[tensor] /.
  (h : (Cycles | Symmetric | Antisymmetric))[list_List] :> h[list + 1]
```

Note that this is a bit rough on the edges and gives incorrect results if `tensor` hasn't been defined as a tensor or is a scalar, but it shouldn't be too hard to improve the code.

The following then works as expected:

```
$Assumptions = m ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]];

TensorRank[CD@m]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
TensorDimensions[CD@m]
```

> ```
> {4, 4, 4}
> ```

```
TensorReduce@TensorTranspose[CD@m, {1, 3, 2}]
```

> ```
> CD[m]
> ```

### Option 2

However, if your covariant derivatives is commutative (like for instance the partial derivative), a better way would be to simply define it as a vector:

```
$Assumptions = CD ∈ Vectors[4, Reals] && m ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]
```

If you like the `CD[tensor]` notation, you may even define

```
CD[tensor_] := TensorProduct[CD, tensor]
```

All the above commands then give the same result. In addition, multiple derivatives are symmetric:

```
TensorSymmetry[CD@CD@m]
```

> ```
> {{Cycles[{{1, 2}}], 1}, {Cycles[{{3, 4}}], 1}}
> ```

So only use this if your derivatives actually commute!

Comment: Since I want to consider non-commuting derivatives I favour option one. Many thanks for this very useful solution!!! Any details about exceptions I will hopefully be able to figure out on my own.

Comment: I think there is an issue with option 2, even if the derivative can be assumed commutative: It will always act on everything on the right. This is because the tensor product is associative, and brackets have no effect. So there is no way to distinguish between D_i A_j B_k = (D_i A_j) B_k + A_j (D_i B_k) and (D_i A_j) B_k

Comment: @Hendrik Yes, that's indeed an issue with option 2. So you can't write CD*T*CD*T (where * is the TensorProduct) to mean (CD@T)*(CD@T) -- yet another reason to opt for option 1!